# Pressing specific keys to do certain things in JavaScript works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, keycode, onkeydown, onkeypress

I'm using 2 functions to detect whether a pressed key matches what I want, and if so, do something. It works like a charm in Chrome, but neither function works in Firefox. Is there a way I can make it work there too?

```js
document.onkeypress = function() {
  if (event.charCode == 49) {
    alert("You pressed 1!");
  }
  if (event.charCode == 50) {
    alert("You pressed 2!");
  }
  if (event.charCode == 51) {
    alert("You pressed 3!");
  }
  if (event.charCode == 52) {
    alert("You pressed 4!");
  }
}

document.onkeydown = function() {
  if (event.keyCode == 122) {
    alert("You pressed F11!");
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Press 1, 2, 3, 4 and F11 to launch different events.</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to declare `event` argument. Perhaprs Chrome do this automatically.
That works in both browsers-

```
document.onkeypress = function(event) {
  if (event.charCode == 49) {
    alert("You pressed 1!");
  }
  if (event.charCode == 50) {
    alert("You pressed 2!");
  }
  if (event.charCode == 51) {
    alert("You pressed 3!");
  }
  if (event.charCode == 52) {
    alert("You pressed 4!");
  }
}

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 122) {
    alert("You pressed F11!");
  }
}
```

Comment: That's way easier than I had imagined, but I couldn't have figured it out on my own. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Note: The answer below from 2016 uses [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/uievent/which), but in new code, use [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) or [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code).

---

The chief issue in that code is that you're relying on the global `event` object, which is not specified in the DOM Events specifications and was a Microsoft-specific thing that Chrome decided to support.

On standards-compliant browsers, you use `addEventListener` and accept the event object as an argument:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    // ....
}, false);
```

If you need to support IE8 and earlier (or IE9+ in their broken "compatibility" mode), you need `attachEvent` which expects you to use the global `event` object:

```
document.attachEvent("onkeypress", function() {
    // ....
});
```

So:

```
function handler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // ...
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", handler, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent("onkeypress", handler);
}
```

The second problem is that `charCode` is deprecated; [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress), you should use `which` for numeric values or (for printable characters) `char` for the (one-character) string. You might fall back to `charCode` or `keyCode` for older browsers.

I'd also use a `switch`.

So:

```js
function handler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    switch (e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode) {
        case 49:
            console.log("You pressed 1");
            break;
        case 50:
            console.log("You pressed 2");
            break;
        case 51:
            console.log("You pressed 3");
            break;
        case 52:
            console.log("You pressed 4");
            break;
    }
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", handler, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent("onkeypress", handler);
}
```

Comment: That's a far more detailed response than I was expecting, and though the other answer solved my issue, I'm interested because this seems more correct. I've seen code blocks similar to that one and people always use "e", is there a reason why? I'd imagine it's "e" as in "event". Also, what's the "(e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode)" bit? I guess it makes the code run if either of those 3 is true, and it's there to make sure it runs on different browsers. What about "e = e || window.event;" though? I have no idea what that does.

Comment: @SoKeT: `e` is just short for `event`, you can use any name there you want (including `event`). `e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode` uses JavaScript's [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to make the value we switch on the first of those properties that has a *truthy* value. `undefined || 49` is `49` in JavaScript, so if a browser doesn't provide `e.which` but does provide one of the others, we'll use the one it provides. We're using that same feature for `e = e || window.event`.

Comment: @SoKeT: Note that if you run the code in that other answer on IE8 or earlier (or in IE9+ in "compatibility mode"), it will fail, because there will be no event argument passed to your handler.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and the blog post, it's all clear now. I don't really need to ensure my code runs on browsers other than Chrome and Firefox, since it's just a project I'm doing for fun and learning purposes, but I'll try to implement your solution instead.